# How to increase HTML table column width using webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm trying to automate a step involved to increase HTML table column width using Selenium webdriver.

Got to know that I can get the index of x and y coordinate with 
`findElement(By.cssSelector("<Css locator>").getLocation();`

But I'd like to know if it was possible to use the same concept to increase the width of a column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Javascript Executor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

```
WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('<CSSLOCATOR>').setAttribute('width', <WIDTH>)");
```

where you fill in `<CSSLOCATOR>` and `<WIDTH>` with what you need.

Comment: See when we try to set width.It set column header value. I mean Javascript is trying to set one field value.Lets say We have Column name "School". If you set width of column header.Javascript executor set only header name in that page.If you go to next page by clicking on next button that is gone case.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question is simple usage of jquery

$(selector).width(value) ;

Example usage
String aScript = "jQuery(\"" + CSS_TABLE_HEADER_BY_COL_NAME + "\").width(%s)";

```
jse.executeScript(aScript );
```

Hope this should resolve most people of increasing column width in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

If its static table then we can add attirbute (not setAttribute, because we need to add new attributed 'width') 'width' with that tag.

```
String tableJS = "document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.width='1000px'";
js.executeScript(tableJS);
```

Note: If cell OR table width is handled by external CSS then this may not work.

2nd Way:If we have resizble table, then we can find the element of 'resizer' and apply below solution by using Action class:

```
if (resizeableElement.isDisplayed()) {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.clickAndHold(resizeableElement).moveByOffset(100, 100).release().build().perform();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element was not displayed to drag");
        }
```